# Why cant all applications run on one single OS?

Tags: server

Before tools like docker and VMs, bare metal servers were used to deploy and host applications. but tools like docker and VM allow us to have more than one OS on the same machine, compared to bare metal server which only allows us to have one OS.

Why is this an issue? Why cant all application run on a single server? why do some apps need a separate/different server?

Comment: It depends on the programming language and architecture of the application. We can't do anything about it.

Comment: @HamzaAnis, could you give an example?

Comment: Virtualization isn't just about operating systems. It's about resource management, security, containment, and being able to migrate services between physical systems. Mainframes have had virtualization for decades for these reasons and more.

Comment: Each operating system’s kernel implements system calls differently so the same binary can not be used for different OS. That's why we need to build the binaries for every OS because the OS can't understand the system calls used by other OS.

Comment: Why on earth would you vote this question down? If this question is not suitable in this forum, then what forum would it be suitable in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications are code, which have been compiled to execute on a certain system.

## Different OS's

Some OS's have different way of doing things and when we code we have to take that into consideration.

For instance in windows paths look like this `c:\this\is\a\path` and in linux they may look like this `/this/is/a/path`. Now if my application is just working with paths I could make my application work on any platform. But I would need to consider how I compile it and what language I run it in, or if its written in a translated language such as python or node.js then I need to ensure that I have written the code in a OS agnostic way. For instance I could reference paths using an OS agnostic way by joining the folders together and not trying to second guess what OS the machine is running on.

If I compile my code from C# but I want it to run on any machine will it check the OS at run time and then alter the way it checks for Paths etc...?

Also an experience I had, where in my web application I had to check if a file was an image, I was using a library which would apperently only work on windows, so when I deployed my docker container to my ubuntu machine I had a run time exception that I had a library missing. It was System.Draw or something. So even once you have your app containerized that may not neccessarily be problem solved

This is just an example with Paths, but that's just an example. Some .NET Framework applications require the machine has special run times installed on it, and these (someone correct me if I'm wrong) wouldn't install on linux, so then the code wouldn't run.

## .NET CORE and Docker

With the advent of .NET Core this is the direction we are trying to move in. For instance .NET Core is supposed to be runable on any platform.

Also with Docker, docker containers wrap everything that is required to run an application into one package, so it doesn't care what your registry settings look like, it doesn't care if your missing the library or that library everything the app needs to run is bundled in with the container. This means if it runs a certain way on system A, then you can expect it will run the same way on system B.

## Architecture

Also we have the issue of 32 and 64 bit architecture. This is basically the rawest level of how information gets processed on the machine. When the code is compiled it is compiled into assembly which your CPU then processes. Depending on whether you have a 32/64 bit machine or OS, this will affect whether the OS and CPU will be able to run the instructions. Yes I believe that 32 bit code can run on a 64 bit machine, but not vice versa. Also if you have an old windows game which uses a 16 bit installer, good luck trying to get that to run . I think I did manage to get an old windows game running in ubuntu in 64 bit. It was a 32 bit game, but the installer was a 16 bit installer.

I'm not expecting this answer will win any awards, but might do as a nice place holder until someone provides a better answer

## Compiled Languages

- Objective C/ Swift - Will this only work on apple devices? ()
- .NET Framework - will mostly work on windows devices, although some code may work on linx via mono
- Java - This is actually cross platform and runs on the Java Run Time, I'm not sure if what it compiles down to is the same for all machines, or whether it has to be compiled into something different for each platform
- c++ Is compiled and what you compile on one OS will not work on another OS.

## Interpreted languages

- Python runs on any machine, atlthough if you want your script or code to be platform agnostic you have to take care
- bash although primarily unix I have seen better support for this on windows lately, I strongly doubt that every script written for unix would run first time on windows without a hitch
- php runs on unix based systems and windows. I'm not sure how much care is requrired to keep this code OS agnostic, although I have a feeling some care may be required.